# Simple single cell populate with Vlookup value

Tags: vba, excel

I am fairly new to VBA, I couldn't really find answer specific to my simple request (most answers were a lot more complicated....). I would like Cell E2 to populate with the result of the vlookup. Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks and sorry if I failed to find a suitable answer..

```
 Sub vlookup_customerror()
       Worksheets("customerror").Activate
         On Error GoTo Errormsg

      Hobbyquery = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("E1"),
      ActiveSheet.Range("A2:B5"), 2, 0)
      Cells("E2").Value = Hobbyquery

     GoTo ending
     Errormsg: GoTo ending

  ending: End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try This: You can add error handler code also

```
Sub custom_error()
Dim result As Integer
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("customerror")
Name = sheet.Range("E1").Value
result = Application.VLookup(Name, sheet.Range("A2:B5"), 2, False)
sheet.Range("E2").Value = result
Debug.Print result
End Sub
```

[image: Sample file]

If you have string data in Column B then change `Dim result As String`

EDIT : To cover the situation , if the lookup value is on other sheet as per 
apprehension expressed by @MacroMarc. In that case please try This:

```
Sub custom_error_v2()
    Dim result As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("E1"), _
      Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:C"), 2, False)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If IsEmpty(result) Then
        MsgBox "Value not found!"
    End If
    Range("E2") = result
End Sub
```

Images of sample data are appended below.

[image: Sample sheet 1][image: Sample sheet 2]

Please make changes to sheet names as per your requirement.

Comment: If the lookup value is on a different sheet to the lookup table, you will need to refernce the lookup value as being specific to that sheet  before activating lookup sheets etc. Perhaps OP is having that problem?

Comment: @MacroMarc I appreciate your viewpoint and try to workout for it, If OP clarifies regarding it.

Comment: @MacroMarc My answer has been updated to cover the apprehension raised by you.

Comment: @macromarc  Hi guys thanks alot, This was my data set.

http://imgur.com/MZJg3e8

am I right to say that the String works only for alphabetical entries and integer only for numerical entries?

thanks alot for the additional error handler too, makes a big difference to my learning ... u guys are amazing.

Comment: @MacroMarc Also, could i ask

sheet.Range("E2").Value = result

why can't I enter sheet.CELL instead of RANGE?

Comment: @eddy you can use ~ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 5) = result~ instead of ~Range("E2") = result~ in version2 of my program code.